# Convert a json to an array in php

Tags: php, json, php-5.3

I have the following json :

```
{
 "AppId": 67876,
 "AppName": "test",
 "Items": [
   "item1"
 ],
 "Signature": "gdfgfdgfdgf",
 "TransactionId": "jhgjg",
 "UserId": "fbgdf"
}
```

I want to transform this json into an array like this :

```
 $aOutput    = json_decode($aJson,true);
```

I don't get any error but the json is not decoded.Can you help me please? Thx in advance

Comment: $aJson must be a string, and what did you get if your var_dump($aOutput); ?

Comment: Works for me: https://eval.in/401618

Comment: Please show us your **full** and **real** code

Comment: I get null if I do var_dump($aOutput)

Comment: then either `$aJson` is null, or an error occured. check `json_last_error()`.

Comment: json_last_error() it's 0

Comment: `<?php
$aJson = '{
 "AppId": 67876,
 "AppName": "test",
 "Items": [
   "item1"
 ],
 "Signature": "gdfgfdgfdgf",
 "TransactionId": "jhgjg",
 "UserId": "fbgdf"
}';

$aOutput = json_decode($aJson,true);

echo '<pre>'.print_r($aOutput, true).'</pre>';
?>` works perfectly so you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Use function `json_last_error` to see exactly what was going on. json_decode just silently returns false if something went wrong.

On my server, your example JSON gets parsed correctly into array. So it will be probably something that is specific to your environment.

Answer (score 0):

So, I found the problem....I make :

```
rtrim($aJson, "\0");
```

And it works. Thx to all